# Yii "results per page" ajax dropdown breaks after loading other ajax stuff in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, yii

I have a view in Yii, the "Patients" view, that has a number of CGridViews and other elements that are ajax loaded after the initial view is loaded. Some are ajax loaded within an already  ajax-loaded div, meaning they are nested 2 levels deep.

In these ajax-loaded CGridViews I have dropdowns that let the user set the number of results per page in each grid.  This works fine until the user loads another element on the page with ajax.  After another grid (or anything else) is loaded by ajax, it breaks all the other results per page ajax functions, except for the one that was just loaded.

After loading anything else with ajax, the other CGridViews will throw this javascript error when using my results per page dropdown:

**TypeError: settings is undefined**

The built-in CGridView pagers always work fine for all grids, so I know there must be some way to let my results per page selector find the correct $.fn.yiiGridView to update.

The controller action that loads the cgridview inline:

```
public function actionInlineSearch()
{
   YiiSessions::model()->setFromRequestCookie();

    $model=new GeneExpressionCufflinksGene('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values 
    // page size drop down changed

    if (isset($_GET['gecgPageSize'])) {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('gecgPageSize',(int)$_GET['gecgPageSize']);
        unset($_GET['gecgPageSize']);  // would interfere with pager and repetitive page size change
    }
    $gecgPageSize=Yii::app()->user->getState('gecgPageSize');

    if(isset($_REQUEST['GeneExpressionCufflinksGene']))
        $model->attributes=$_REQUEST['GeneExpressionCufflinksGene'];

    $this->renderPartial('inlineSearch',array('model'=>$model,'gecgPageSize'=>$gecgPageSize), false, true);
}
```

The inlineSearch view that loads the CGridView widget:

```
 // $columns[]='normal_allele_depth';
// $columns[]='normal_allele_freq';

echo "<div class='results-selector'>";
echo "Results per page: ". 
    CHtml::dropDownList('gecgPageSize',$gecgPageSize,array(10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100),array(
        'onchange'=>"
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('gecg',{ data:{gecgPageSize: $(this).val() }});
        ",
    ));
echo "</div>";

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'gecg',
   'filter'=>$model,
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, 
   'columns'=>$columns,
));
?>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: after a lot of messing around I decided to manually stash `settings` + `$.fn.yiiGridView` in a window variable at the end of each of the inlineSearch views, then retrieve them from window when my items per page selector is changed.

This is not a very elegant solution (especailly since the pagers were working fine, and it will result in multiple $.fn.yiiGridView instances floating around) but oh well. It works, and although I'm still somewhat of a noob at Yii, but I can tell by my research that there are some unresolved issues with multiple ajax loaded widgets.

New results per page element in the inlineSearch view:

```
echo "<div class='results-selector'>";
echo "Results per page: ". 
    CHtml::dropDownList('gecgPageSize',$gecgPageSize,array(10=>10,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100),array(
        'onchange'=>"
            $.fn.yiiGridView=window.gecgGridView; // necessary in case other other ajax load doesn't have the yiigridview js
            $.fn.yiiGridView.settings['gecg']=window.gecgGridSettings; // because it will have been clobbered by other ajax grid load
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('gecg',{ data:{ gecgPageSize: $(this).val() }});
        ",
    ));
echo "</div>";
```

at the end of inlineSearch view, this saves `settings` in `window`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){ 
    window.gecgGridView=$.fn.yiiGridView;
    window.gecgGridSettings={
                            ajaxUpdate:["gecg"],
                            ajaxVar:"ajax",
                            pagerClass:"pager",
                            filterClass:"filters",
                            loadingClass:"grid-view-loading",
                            pageVar:"GeneExpressionCufflinksGene_page",
                            pagerClass:"GeneExpressionCufflinksGene_page",
                            selectableRows:1,
                            tableClass:"items",
                            updateSelector:"#gecg .pager a, #gecg .items thead th a",
                            afterAjaxUpdate:function(){}
                          };
})
</script>
```

Comment: As a side note, I later had to modify the CGridView framework code to not create duplicate events from reloading that widget multiple times.  Not optimal but it wasn't designed to be loaded via ajax inline.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I got everything you have written but are you confident that pagers of two-depth loaded `CGridView`'s work?

Yii attaches event handlers to pagers' buttons, sorting buttons, buttons of [CButtonColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn) class using jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. If you specify `selector` parameter then event will be triggered for all matched descendants of jQuery element `on()` method is called on, for both existing and non-existing at the moment of this call.

Yii attaches handlers to `document` element that always exist (and must exist to allow events to be triggered) on the page. You can see it as an example in `CGridView`'s `init` method in `zii/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js`:

```
settings.updateSelector = settings.updateSelector
    .replace('{page}', pagerSelector)
    .replace('{sort}', sortSelector);

gridSettings[id] = settings;

if (settings.ajaxUpdate.length > 0) {
    $(document).on('click.yiiGridView', settings.updateSelector, function () {
        // Check to see if History.js is enabled for our Browser
        if (settings.enableHistory && window.History.enabled) {
            // ...
        } else {
            $('#' + id).yiiGridView('update', {url: $(this).attr('href')});
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

So I suppose if you render `CGridView` widget on ajax request then all event handlers for pagers, sorting and etc will be attached to partially rendered `document` element of ajax page but not to the one of your main page that new loaded elements will belong to. Probably the same thing happens with your dropdown list if you load your `inlineSearch` view through ajax.

That's why, as I can see, all event handlers must be attached to `document` element of your main non-ajax view that initially loads the page.

Comment: I'm certain the pager works in all the ajax loaded grids, even after reloading others. I'm trying to make the grid settings global or attached to document after each grid loads. Still not sure about the best approach though.  Thanks.